# Passing string instead of node while creating a XML file in java

Tags: java, xml, string, xmlnode

I would like to create a XML file which would have all the information about the system.
To get the information, i would use `getProperty(os.name)` and would save it in a string like this

```
String nameOS = "os.name";  
nameOS=System.getProperty(nameOS);
```

And now i would like to create an XML and would like the value of this string to be one of the element of XML file created, for which i would be doing something like this

```
Element Osname = doc.createElement("Osname");
Osname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("nameOS"));
staff.appendChild(Osname);
```

But Output xml file looks likes this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?> 
- <HardwareInfo>
  <OsName>nameOS</OsName>  
  </HardwareInfo>
```

I get the name of the string in the output instead of Value of the string.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the quotes from around nameOs

```
Osname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nameOS));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Osname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("nameOS"));`

Should be

`Osname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nameOS));`